# Gluon application got problem when MousePressed fast click or double, tripple click

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have develop the gluon application which use `uuid` to generate the BarCode and QRCODE. The use could switch between Barcode and Qrcode based on shop. The Barcode will show only in the portrait screen mode when use click on QRCODE (Image). So the screen will auto rotate based when the user click on Image (Barcode/QRcode).

```
this.img.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
//Rotate Screen
        Services.get( CMOrientationService.class ).ifPresent( o -> {
            Orientation orientation = Services.get( OrientationService.class )
                    .flatMap(OrientationService::getOrientation)
                    .orElse(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

            Services.get(LogService.class).ifPresent(service -> service.log("orientation="+orientation.toString()));

            if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                Services.get(LogService.class).ifPresent(service -> service.log("Currently="+orientation.toString()));
                //Change to Barcode
                //GenerateBarQRCode(orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL);
                o.coerceOrientation( Orientation.HORIZONTAL );
            } else {
                Services.get(LogService.class).ifPresent(service -> service.log("Currently="+orientation.toString()));
                //Change to QRCode
                //GenerateBarQRCode(orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL);
                o.coerceOrientation( Orientation.VERTICAL );
            }
            GenerateBarQRCode(orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL);
        } );
});
```

The problems occurs when user trying to click fast on the image (double, triple click) it will generate wrong.

You can check [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a2KF0H2fVwUteojj_CvgM8wOOWRfnwHN/view) for more understanding (Look at 6 sec in the video).

Noted. It error only in Android.

Comment: Maybe this is a synchronization issue, you can try synchronizing the code inside the onMousePressed event so that it could handle multiple touches. You can also use atomic flag which is unset while processing and is set when the processing is completed i.e after GenerateBarQRCode method, the code should not be executed while the flag is unset. Using this the unwanted touches will be consumed and not executed.

Comment: Can you give me some code?

Comment: Not sure if this'll work, but you could check [the `clickCount` property of the `MouseEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount()) and only trigger the change, if it's 1. If that does not work, consider storing the time of the last change of the orientation triggered by this event handler and make sure the logic is only executed, if there a certain time has passed since the last orientation change.

Comment: @fabian When I use clickCount on desktop, it working well. But in Android clickCount always 1, So if we double click, this event fired twice.

Comment: @fabian: yeah, If we delay to 1000 milliseconds, it work. but It effect to performance, It show black screen when application was delay. So this solution worked, but I don't think it is good idea to use it.

Comment: That's not what I was suggesting. I was suggesting saving the time of the update. `if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate >= 1000) { /* do update */ lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis(); }` (or using some delay other than 1000 ms)

Comment: It worked perfect, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use synchronization like this

```
// At class level
private Object mutex;
//initialize this object in constructor like this
mutex = this;

this.img.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
//Rotate Screen
synchronized(mutex){
// your code here
       ....
}
});
```

However in above instance, multiple click events will be executed in serial fashion. If you want that multiple clicks should be ignored until execution then you can use following code snippet

```
// At class level
private boolean mutex = true;

this.img.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
   if(mutex){
     mutex = false;

        // your code here
               ....
     mutex = true;
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Thank for your answer, but It doesn't work. The problem still exist

Comment: JavaFX events are all executed on a single thread. It's not an issue with concurent threads. If it was, the second implementation is not guaranteed to communicate changes of the `mutex` field between threads...